# How do I scan specific numbers in an array from a text?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a text input and I'm trying to scan every third number. I could only scan every number, but not specifically every third number

```
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("budgettracker.txt"));
    int counter = 0;
    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter ("textout.text");
    while(inFile.hasNextInt())
    {
        counter++;
        inFile.nextInt();
    }
    Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new FileReader("budgettracker.txt"));
    int a[] = new int[counter];
        for (int p = 0; p<counter; p++)
        {
            if(a[p] == a[0] || a[p] == a[3] || a[p] == a[6])
            {
            a[p] = inFile1.nextInt();
            outFile.print(a[p] + " ");
            }
        }

        outFile.close();
        inFile.close();
    }
```

Comment: You mean, you want to scan the 3rd line of your text file?

Comment: the third number actually i'm sorry i should add the text input 
500 400 100
300 200 200
900 200 150

I want to scan only 500, 300, and 900

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean.  Is this what you're looking for?

```
int index = 0;
for (int p = 0; p<counter; p++)
{
  if(p%3 == 0) // Every third number
  {
    a[index] = inFile1.nextInt();
    outFile.print(a[index++] + " ");
  }else{
    inFile1.nextInt(); // Skip if the line isn't a multiple of 3
  }
}
```

Comment: i've tried your answer but it only prints out the first number

Comment: Sorry!  I was using the wrong index for the array.  I fixed it now.

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  I just ran this exact example (with the rest of your code) and it prints `500 300 900` to the file "textout.text"